# Ran 'git checkout stash' and now want to overwrite an existing branch with my current unattached branch that i had stashed

Tags: git

So I messed up a bit in my branches and they weren't building, fortunately I had the project working stashed so i did a

```
git checkout stash
```

and that reverted my project to building successfully. I now want to overwrite an existing branch called 'develop' with my current unattached branch. Essentially i just want the name of the 'develop' branch but i want everything in it gone and replaced with my current stash branch. For reference when i run

```
git s
```

currently i get:

```
## HEAD (no branch)
?? Project/Setup_BACKUP_38164.swift
?? Project/Setup_BASE_38164.swift
?? Project/Setup_LOCAL_38164.swift
?? Project/Setup_REMOTE_38164.swift
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want to do a `git show` to get the SHA1 commit ID of the current HEAD. With that information, switch to the **develop** branch and run the command:

```
git merge abc123
```

Where "abc123" is the SHA1 ID.

Comment: Alternatively, you can create a temporary branch and merge that branch into develop by running: 'git checkout -b temp_branch_name', commit the files to that branch, switch the the develop branch and run 'git merge temp_branch_name'

Comment: How do I handle the fact that I don't want to merge with develop, I want to "overwrite" it instead and basically put my stash in exactly as it is, without having to go through a merge?

Comment: If there isn't anything on develop that would be lost, it would be easiest to delete the develop branch and recreate it. That can be done by running: 'git branch -D develop' then 'git branch -b develop'. After that, you can commit your files and you should be set.

Comment: Also, if you have already pushed the develop branch to a remote origin, you will want to also run 'git push origin :develop", to delete the branch on origin also. That will avoid merging the branch on origin with the old and new version.

Comment: ok thank you! So just to clarify, if I remove the current develop branch and then create a new one, and then do a commit of my stash from where I am(HEAD), then when I jump over to checkout the new develop branch, it will be just like my stash in head?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. You will remove the branch and when you checkout -b the new branch, it will automatically switch you to that branch, at which time you can commit your files to the new develop branch.